# Why is my Pearson Coefficient Heat map returning Nan values?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

[image]I am trying to calculate the Pearson coefficient for all columns in my dataframe but when I try to make a heatmap I return Nan values in rows with zeroes in them.  Any suggestions on how to fix it? Here is the screenshot of the code and output below:

```
#Calculate the correlation coefficients
corr = dfno.corr(method ='pearson') 
#plot it in the next line
corr.round(2).style.background_gradient(cmap='coolwarm')
```

[image: Pearson Heatmap]

Answer (score 1):

`NaN` appears if at least one of your columns is **constant values**. If a column is a constant value, its standard deviation would be 0 and results in a division by 0, hence `NaN` in Pearson's correlation. Depending on your application, I think easiest way to deal with them is to replace `NaN`s with 0 in your heatmap output.

```
corr.fillna(0)
```

Comment: Yeah makes sense now that you pointed that out. Thanks!